# Why is SVG rendering faster than a typical HTML tag?

Tags: html, svg

https://bradfrost.com/blog/link/thinking-about-react-atomically/

As you can see from the page on the link above, there are quite a few SVG Circles at the top and bottom of the website.
If it was normal HTML, there would be a significant negative impact on website performance, but this site is not. How is that possible?

Comment: Load the page with Javascript disabled, and watch those pretty circles disappear. The page is using Javascript to load them after-the-fact.

Comment: What makes you think that "SVG rendering is faster than a typical HTML tag"? How have you measured that?

Comment: There are no objectively measured data. Our experience in developing applications such as chat has shown that if more than 100 elements are repeatedly rendered on a web page, the website will slow down.

Thank you for your answer.